# UART serial access with Rpi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am trying to establish a serial connection between the RPI3 and an Arduino. Because that wasn't working I connected a USB to TTY cable from my laptop to the Rx/Tx pins of RPI. I was eventually able to use PuTTy to connect to it. 
I am running Android Things on the RPI and the android code I have running is supposed to be a loopback (reading from UART and writing back what was read).

Here is where I am confused....
When PuTTy connected I was presented with a command line console on the RPI.

How do I get the Rx/Tx pins on the RPI to just be serial connections into and from my application and NOT a way to log into the console?

Is that a bad idea? I suppose if I ever needed to log into the RPI this would make it more difficult...

Comment: You need to find a way to disconnect SSH/terminal shell access from the serial port.  It's a nice fallback to have in case you ever kill the network stack. Find the serial port designation/file then Google how to connect a port to shell.  Then reverse that process bro :)

Comment: This shows you how to do it... http://raspberrypihobbyist.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/raspberry-pi-serial-port.html

Comment: I did see some tutorials such as this...however the 'sudo' command and the 'vi' (or vim) commands do not work, they are not found.
/system/bin/sh: sudo: not found

Is this because I am using Android things? Are these tutorials only for Raspberry Pi?
Some commands like 'ps' and 'ls' work, but I can't open either of these files to update as the tutorial shows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong...
When following the setup directions at the below site I was using the Bluetooth mode instead of the Application mode. When I followed the directions for Application mode I was able to start using UART0 for serial comms

Set the console attribute to the following in cmdline.txt:

```
console=tty0
```

Add the following line in config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

Remove the following lines from config.txt:

```
enabled_uart=1
core_freq=400
```

https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#disabling_the_console

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with [Developer Preview 3](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_3), in which USB-Serial devices support added, You can use external USB-UART dongles like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12731) instead of UART of Raspberry Pi 3.